# Make a Tank Aim Properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I am trying to make my tank fire, but it doesn't seem to work.
My tank's gun has a firing point which is used to fire the object. FirePoint is the point from which the laser beam is instantiated. When I turn my turret though the point goes off. The point is a child of the gun turret. What do I need to do? If I haven't explained it enough, please ask and I will try my best to help.

This is my player controller script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
public float Speed = 0;
public float MaxSpeed;
public float TurnSpeed;
public float AccelRate = 1;
public float BrakeSpeed = 1;
public GameObject LaserBeam;
public GameObject FirePoint;
public Vector3 Offset;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    // Increase forward when up arrow pressed
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        Speed = Speed + AccelRate;
    }
    // Move backward when down arrow pressed
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        Speed = Speed - AccelRate;
    }
    // Turn when left arrow pressed
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * TurnSpeed);
    }
    // Turn when right arrow pressed
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * TurnSpeed);
    }
    // Reset vehicle rotation
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Return))
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }
    // Press the brakes
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && (Speed > 0 || Speed < 0))
    {
        Speed = Speed - BrakeSpeed;
        if (Speed < 0) { Speed = 0; }
    }
    //Ensure vehicle does not pass the maxspeed
    if (Speed > MaxSpeed)
    {
        Speed = MaxSpeed;
    }
    //Move vehicle
    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * Speed);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) == false && Speed > 0)
    {
        Speed = Speed - AccelRate;
    }
    //Fire
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
    {
        Instantiate(LaserBeam, FirePoint.transform.position + Offset, FirePoint.transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it! I simply set the offset to 0,0,0 and it worked.